# Tables stacked below each other in csv - How do I import them in R?

Tags: r, csv, tibble, readr

I have a csv file that looks like this

```
Header, Car, LapTime
1, Spa, 0
0, Ferrari, 2.1
0, Aston Martin, 2.3
1, Monza, 0
0, Ferrari, 2.5
0, Ford, 2.6
0, Aston Martin, 2.4
```

That is, the csv contains multiple subtables stacked below each other, where the header of each subtable has `header = 1`. I don't know how many rows each sub-table has and how many sub-tables there are.

Now I would like to import this csv (preferably as a tidyverse tbl) to have it in R represented as

```
Car, LapTime, Circuit
Ferrari, 2.1, Spa
Aston Martin, 2.3, Spa
Ferrari, 2.5, Monza
Ford, 2.6, Monza
Aston Martin, 2.4, Monza
```

I cannot come up with a programmatic way to do this. Do you have an idea?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Read the file (see Note at end to reproduce it) and grouping by `cumsum(Header)` add the `Circuit` column, remove the first row of the group and remove the `Header` column.

```
library(dplyr)
library(readr)

"cars.csv" %>%
  read_csv %>%
  group_by(Header = cumsum(Header)) %>%
  mutate(Circuit = first(Car)) %>%
  slice_tail(n = -1) %>%
  ungroup %>%
  select(-Header)
```

giving

```
# A tibble: 5 × 3
  Car          LapTime Circuit
  <chr>          <dbl> <chr>  
1 Ferrari          2.1 Spa    
2 Aston Martin     2.3 Spa    
3 Ferrari          2.5 Monza  
4 Ford             2.6 Monza  
5 Aston Martin     2.4 Monza
```

### Note

```
Lines <- "Header, Car, LapTime
1, Spa, 0
0, Ferrari, 2.1
0, Aston Martin, 2.3
1, Monza, 0
0, Ferrari, 2.5
0, Ford, 2.6
0, Aston Martin, 2.4
"
cat(Lines, file = "cars.csv")
```